# Keycloak consent

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I have a question about the Keycloak's consent.

I would like to know if it is possible to individualize the granting of consent.

Currently, when a customer logs in to the keycloak he can allow all scopes or deny all, I would like him to be able to select which one he wants to allow.

For example, today it presents this way:

[image]

I would like to segregate into something like:

[image]

Would it be possible? checking the keycloak documentation I did not find such information.

Thanks